# What are "post-treatment confounders" and "pre-treatment confounders"?

Tags: causality, mediation, confounding

I am reading the [vignette for the R mediation package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf).

At page 4 it makes the sequential ignorability assumption, and says that

> Equation 6 requires that the mediator is also ignorable given the observed treatment and pre-treatment confounders. This additional assumption is quite strong because ut excludes the existence of (measured or unmeasured) post-treatment confounders as well as that of unmeasured pre-treatment confounders.

What are "post-treament confounders" and what are "pre-treatment counfounders"?

I know what a confounder is, but I don't know what the qualifiers "pre-treatment" and "post-treatment" mean in this context.

Comment: Well, what would you say a confounder is?

Comment: @AdrianKeister A variable that determines both treatment and outcome

Comment: As causes must precede effects, so a confounder as you've defined it must precede the treatment. A so-called "post-treatment confounder" isn't actually a confounder. It might be a mediator, but it can't set up a backdoor path from the treatment to the effect because the causal arrow is going *out* of the treatment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of mediation analysis, there are two causal variables of interest: the treatment and the mediator. Pre-treatment confounders are common causes of the treatment, mediator, and/or outcome that are measured before treatment. Adjusting for these is necessary for consistent estimates of the mediation effects, but there are many ways to do so in a straightforward manner (including using the `mediation` package). Post-treatment confounders are common causes of the mediator and outcome that are measured after treatment. These are more challenging to address, and the methods that underlie the `mediation` package are not equipped to address them. They are particularly problematic because if they are caused by treatment, conditioning on them in the mediation analysis will induce post-treatment selection bias (Elwert & Winship, 2014).

See the graph below, which comes from Acharya, Blackwell, and Sen (2016):

[image]

The variable $Z$ is a post-treatment (i.e., intermediate) confounder. Although many mediation methods require the assumption that these do not exist, in reality, they very likely do, especially if there is a lot of time between the treatment and the measurement of the mediator.

---

Acharya, A., Blackwell, M., & Sen, M. (2016). Explaining Causal Findings Without Bias: Detecting and Assessing Direct Effects. American Political Science Review, 110(3), 512–529. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0003055416000216

Elwert, F., & Winship, C. (2014). Endogenous Selection Bias: The Problem of Conditioning on a Collider Variable. Annual Review of Sociology, 40(1), 31–53. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-soc-071913-043455